# Sequence increment is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

I created a sequence by using following query :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSeq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

It was working. I dropped the sequence and created again and now it is not working. It just shows 1 for all the records and this is no sense.

I also tried to use the following query and it didn't solve the problem, either :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSeq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```

Please don't suggest creating identity column in 12c. Because I need to use sequence column in ODI and I have to specify a surrogate column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not use `TestSeq.currval` instead of `TestSeq.nextval` somewhere inside your code ?

Comment: Not that it will make any difference here, but in general `create sequence testseq;` is the standard command to create a sequence object. There is no need to specify `start with 1` etc as that's the default anyway. `NOCACHE` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: It would help to show the statements you are running and the output you get. Perhaps you are doing a single `insert all` to insert multiple rows, for instance, which would only increment the sequence once however many rows are inserted. We shouldn't need to try to guess what you are doing and seeing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this at all. Please run the following code and show us what is displayed.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSeq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

select testseq.nextval from dual
/

select testseq.nextval from dual
/

select testseq.nextval from dual
/
```